# OnChange angular is not printing the exact value

Tags: angular, onchange

I'm trying to retrieve value from a select box on Onchange event: 
here is the code I tried :

html:

```
<select  (change)="onChangeObj($event.target.value)">
    <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let x of fruits" [ngValue]="x.code"> {{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

ts:

```
onChangeObj(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

When I'm printing the value it is printing: 
1: AP
2: OR
etc..  how can I print the exact value ('AP', 'OR') without 1: , 2: etc...

example Json :

`Json : { name: "Orange", code: "OR", description: "Orange fruit" }, { name: "Apple", code: "AP", description: "Apple friut" }

when use ($event.target.value).. I'm getting '2: AP' , '1: OR' like that not sure where this numbers are adding.. so now I want only 'OR', 'AP'etc..

Comment: What is the issue actually? Are you wanting the actual `value` of an `<option>` to be just "orange" instead of "2: orange"? Or are you asking how to remove "2:" from "2: orange" inside `onChangeObj()`?

Comment: I want only 'orange' instead of '2: orange'

Comment: But where exacly? Do you want the HTML to be `<option value="2: orange"></option>` or ``<option value="orange"></option>`? "2: orange" is happening because you are specifying `[ngValue]="x.code"`. No matter what, you can remove stuff like "2:" from a string using regex and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). You try `replace()` first then update your question if you still are having issues removing "1:", "2:", etc.

Comment: fruits is list like below Json : {
code: "Orange",
description: "Orange fruit"
},
{
name: "Apple",
code: "Apple",
description: "Apple friut"
},.  when  use ($event.target.value).. I'm getting '2: Apple' , '1: Orange' like that not surer where this numbers are adding.. so now I want only 'Orange', Apple etc..

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zye1j8 please make your own stackblitz that shows the issue you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is correct.
[Check your code in action in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxhzaw)

Maybe, something is going wrong in your side.

Comment: I found the issue. that is the problem with mapping the response from DB to json(). here is what I wrote http.get(someurl).map(res=>res.json()); when I'm doing like this it is converting that as array and appending 1: , 2: etc before each element